# Converting code using wmi to code using ffmpy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wmi

I have the following code that prints out the names of USB cameras connected to my PC:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
for item in c.query(wql):
    a = item.Dependent.PNPClass
    b = item.Dependent.Name.upper()
    if (a.upper() == 'MEDIA' or a.upper() == 'CAMERA') and 'AUDIO' not in b:
        print(item.Dependent.Name)
```

The problem with this code is that it only works in Windows. I want to alter this code so that it works on all operating systems. I know that I have to use something other than wmi, since wmi only works in Windows. So, I was thinking about using an ffmpeg wrapper called ffmpy. So maybe I could convert the code to use ffmpy? I got the code above from the following SO post: [Associate USB Video Capture Device Friendly Name with OpenCV Port Number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130625/associate-usb-video-capture-device-friendly-name-with-opencv-port-number-in-pyth). Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this question is no; there is no OS-independent way of getting the names of USB cameras connected to your PC. However, there is platform-specific code that can get the job done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68402011/13386603

Answer (score 1):

You can give `pygrabber` a shot. "# This code lists the cameras connected to your PC:"   [(source)](https://github.com/andreaschiavinato/python_grabber)

```
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

graph = FilterGraph()
print(graph.get_input_devices())

# ['Integrated Webcam', 'EpocCam Camera']
```

Comment: Actually, when I look at the documentation, this seems to only work for windows...is there an alternative that works for all OS's?

Comment: Are you sure? i dont have apple pc to test it.

Comment: It says in the pygrabber repo that it only works for windows.

Comment: Realy? I double checked it; but i cant see sorry.